# Is it possible to install an Android app with additional config information?

Tags: android, parameters, installation

is it possible to give some information to the installation process of Android applications?

When a user is sent to the market from my website, I would like to somehow link the installation process to his user login. That way he can skip one step and it becomes much smoother in total (I hope).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can use the user's Accounts on the device to authenticate with a Google Account for example, see:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't really notice the msg before and was a little disappointed to get no answer!